MttDemo Error, Can't found bean MqttGeteway

Parameter 0 of constructor in
com.mqtt.ecmqtt.controller.MqttController required a bean of type
'com.mqtt.ecmqtt.mqtt.gateway.MqttGateway' that could not be found.

Why does it say there is no such bean?
Error details: https://github.com/QingYiShiDeCha/Mqtt-Demo
I tried to customize the implementation class of the Mqttgateway, but the console still prompts an error and is null. After deleting it, it prompted that there was no bean. What is the problem? How to solve it?
mqtt:
  broker-url:
   - tcp://broker-cn.emqx.io:1883
  username: emqx
  password: public
  client-id: mqttClientId
  connection-timeout: 3000
  default-topic: test/topic
  subscription-topic:
    - qingcha
    - topicA

@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mqtt")
public class MqttProperties {
    private String[] brokerUrl;
    private String clientId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String defaultTopic;
    private Long connectionTimeout;
    private String[] subscriptionTopic;
}

@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class MqttConfig {
    @Autowired
    private MqttProperties mqttProperties;


    @Bean
    public MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions() {
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName(mqttProperties.getUsername());
        options.setPassword(mqttProperties.getPassword().toCharArray());
        options.setServerURIs(mqttProperties.getBrokerUrl());
        return options;
    }

    /**
     * 创建MqttPahoClientFactory，设置MQTT Broker连接属性，如果使用SSL验证，也在这里设置。
     *
     * @return factory
     */
    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        factory.setConnectionOptions(mqttConnectOptions());

        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * 发送通道
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttOutputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        MqttPahoMessageHandler handler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler(mqttProperties.getClientId(), mqttClientFactory());
        // 如果设置为true, 即异步, 发送消息将不对阻塞
        handler.setAsync(true);
        handler.setDefaultTopic(mqttProperties.getDefaultTopic());
        return handler;
    }

    /**
     * 接收通道
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /**
     * 配置client监听的topic
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageProducer messageProducer() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqttProperties.getClientId() + "_input", mqttClientFactory(), mqttProperties.getSubscriptionTopic());
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(mqttProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler mqttInputHandler() {
        return new ReceiveMessageHandler();
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class ReceiveMessageHandler implements MessageHandler {

    @Resource
    private SensorMapper sensorMapper;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        String topic = Objects.requireNonNull(message.getHeaders().get("mqtt_receivedTopic")).toString();
        log.info("Receive message from topic {}", topic);
        if ("hello".equalsIgnoreCase(topic)) {
            log.info("hello: {}", message.getPayload());
        } else {
            try {
                String payload = message.getPayload().toString();
                SensorData sensorData = JSON.parseObject(payload, SensorData.class);
                log.info("receive data: {}", sensorData);

                sensorMapper.insert(sensorData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutputChannel")
public interface MqttGateway {
    /**
     * 向默认topic发送消息
     *
     * @param data 数据
     */
    void sendToMqtt(String data);

    /**
     * 指定 topic 进行消息发送
     *
     * @param data  数据
     * @param topic 主题
     */
    void sendToMqtt(String data, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic);

    /**
     * 指定 topic 和 qos 进行消息发送
     *
     * @param data  数据
     * @param topic 主题
     * @param qos   服务质量
     */
    void sendToMqtt(String data, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic, @Header(MqttHeaders.QOS) int qos);
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mqtt")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MqttController {
    private final MqttGateway mqttGateway;

    @PostMapping("/send")
    public String sendMsg(String data) {
        mqttGateway.sendToMqtt(data);
        return "success";
    }

    /**
     * 发送mqtt消息
     *
     * @param data  负载
     * @param topic 话题
     * @return String
     */
    @PostMapping("/topic/send")
    public String sendMsg(String data, String topic) {
        mqttGateway.sendToMqtt(data, topic);
        return "success";
    }
}


The bean might not be on the classpath at runtime. Or the bean does not auto-register to Spring as managed bean therefore you need to do it.

Think you, I found a solution

Want to post it? Then your question counts as answered and may help others.
